# Como excluir uma classe específica do querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde utilizo modais do bootstrap, por um problema de sobreposição de alguns elementos, precisei utilizar um script que sempre atribui o maior valor `z-index` +10 da página à nova modal aberta, para que não haja esse problema.

Acontece que estou utilizando outro plugin que mostra notificações no topo da tela, e as notificações estão ficando atrás da modal.

Para pegar o maior z-index da página utilizo o seguinte código:

```
var zIndex = Math.max.apply(null,Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'), function (el) {
    return +el.style.zIndex;
})) + 10;
```

Tem alguma maneira de continuar pegando todos os seletores (*) menos a classe `.notifications` com o `.querySelectorAll()` ?

Comment: Tente usar `not` para excluir, algo como: `querySelectorAll('*:not(.notifications)')`

Comment: @LucasCosta Perfeito, valeu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa **not:** CSS pseudo-class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*:not(.notifications)');
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.